# for columnX of each element in listA <- corresponding element in listB

Tags: r, list, vector, dataframe, apply

I have two lists, one consisting of data.frames and one of character vectors of the same length as the data.frames. I would like to swap/overwrite column `X1` in list `ls.df` for the corresponding character vector in `ls.v`. Basically as `df$X1 <- v` but for each item in lists. It feels so simple, but I can't get around it.

```
#dummy data

df1 <- data.frame(rbind(c(1,'A'),c(2,'B'),c(3,'C'),c(4,'D'),c(5,'E'),c(6,'F')))
df2 <- data.frame(rbind(c(1,'A'),c(2,'B'),c(3,'C')))
df3 <- data.frame(rbind(c(4,'D'),c(5,'E'),c(6,'F')))

ls.df <- list(df1, df2, df3)

v1 <- c('a','b','c','d','e','f')
v2 <- c('a','b','c')
v3 <- c('d','e','f')

ls.v <- list(v1, v2, v3)
```

Is there a e.g. `apply-like` way to do this? Any pointer would be highly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mapply`.

The lists:

```
ls.df <- list(df1, df2, df3)
ls.v <- list(v1, v2, v3)
```

The solution:

```
mapply("[[<-", ls.df, value = ls.v, MoreArgs = list(1L), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

The result:

```
[[1]]
  X1 X2
1  a  A
2  b  B
3  c  C
4  d  D
5  e  E
6  f  F

[[2]]
  X1 X2
1  a  A
2  b  B
3  c  C

[[3]]
  X1 X2
1  d  D
2  e  E
3  f  F
```

Comment: Big thanks! I tried `mapply` but have to learn more about the use of indexing using `"["`